# Proof verification : $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory

To show that : $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable

> Set $A$ is said to be countable if there exists a bijection from $A$
>   to $\mathbb{N}$. Every countable set is infinite.
>
> Further I have proved the following results:
>
> 1. Set $A$ is finite or countable $\iff$ $\exists f:N\to A $ a surjection $\iff \exists g:A\to N$ an injection.
> 2. Let $f:S\to T$ an injection where $T$ is countable and $S$ is infinite, then $S$ has to be countable. This result follows directly
>      from 1.

$\mathbb{Q}= \{p/q \; | \; p\in Z,\; q\in N, (p,q)=1\}$

define. $f:\mathbb{Q}\to \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{N}$ as the identity map which is an injection too.

Now, $\mathbb{Q}$ is infinite as $\mathbb{N}\subset \mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{N} $ is countable.

Also $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{N}$ is countable as $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{N}$ are countable and using the fact finite product of countable is countable.

Hence by 2. above $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable.

Is this proof okay?

Comment: This looks ok to me. In fact you can even inject directly into $\mathbb N$ via stuff like $(p,q)\mapsto 2^p3^q$.

Comment: @zwim $p$ can be negative. One could do $(p,q)\mapsto 2^q3^p$ if $p\ge0$, $2^q5^{-p}$ if $p<0$.

Comment: You can also consider the [Stern-Brocot tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stern–Brocot_tree) that is obviously countable and contains every positive rational.

Comment: just want to know if my method above is correct or not

Comment: Basically, yes.  The one tiny flaw is that you need to choose a canonical way of expressing a rational.  Just requiring $q \gt 0$ solves the problem.

Comment: "define. f:Q→Z×N as the identity map which is an injection too."  I think you should explicitly define what this is.  "the identity map which is an injection too" doesn't make any sense to me.  I'm pretty sure you mean that if $f(q) = $ the unique relatively prime pair $(m,n)\in \mathbb Z\times \mathbb N$ where $\gcd(m,n) =1$ and $q=\frac mn$ but I think you need to state this.

Comment: Yes you are right, I should mention explicitly

Comment: It is customary that "countable" means "finite or countably infinite" so that "uncountable" and "not countable" both mean "uncountably infinite".

Comment: If you have a theorem that the Cartesian product of countable sets is countable (and indeed one exists), then, indeed, you are done.  IMHO the hard part is proof of that theorem.

Answer (score 0):

Alternate proof.
As |Q| <= |Z×Z| and the latter is countable, Q is countable.
Since Q is infinite, it is countablely infinite, hence equinumerous to N.